# Java8 Stream API: Group a list into a custom class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to construct a custom class instance by Java8's stream API.

```
public class Foo {
    Group group;
    // other properties

    public Group getGroup() { return this.group; }

    public enum Group { /* ... */ };
}

public class FooModel {
    private Foo.Group group;
    private List<Foo> foos;

    // Getter/Setter
}

...

List<Foo> inputList = getFromSomewhere();

List<FooModel> outputList = inputList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getGroup,
                                   ???));
```

But I don't know how the `Collector downstream` must be.
Do I have to implement a `Collector` myself (don't think so) or can this be accomplished by a combination of `Collectors.` calls?

Comment: Why are you grouping? What do you want as result? Can you post an example of input / output?

Comment: I really don't get the question after rereading it three times. Would you mind being more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
List<FooModel> outputList = inputList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getGroup))// create Map<Foo.Group,List<Foo>>
.entrySet().stream() // go through entry set to create FooModel
.map(
entry-> new FooModel (
entry.getKey(),
entry.getValue()
)
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```